# mixing up ajax and jsp to get data into a servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I've got a jsp file with two text fields (signUp and post). Now, I want the post text and the signUp text to be called to a servlet. Normally its going with `request.getParameter()`, but now I want the post text going to the servlet with an AJAX function and the signup text with the normal way (that means the name of the input within the jsp file and then request.getParameter).

Is it possible to mix both parts within one servlet because i have this:

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="PostWallServlet" id="form1">
```

form1 is the ajax code. I don't know how this should work. Normally there stands

```
`<form action="PostWallServlet"  method="POST" >
```

and everything is callable through the Servlet. But, for now I don't know how I can mix up both components.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PostWall pw=new PostWall();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current Date Time : " + df.format(cal.getTime()));

    String message = "";
    String sender = request.getParameter("sender");  
    String post = request.getParameter("message");
    String a= df.format(cal.getTime()).toString();

    pw.setSender(sender);
    pw.setPost(post);
    pw.setDate(a);
    if (pwi.addPost(pw)) {  
           message = "Student Successfuly Added";  
          } else {  
           message = "Student Adding Failed";  
          }  

    //RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("post.jsp");  
      //rd.forward(request, response);  
}




$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#Add').click(function(){
           sendData();
    });
   });
function sendData(){
   var mge = $('#newText').val();
    alert(mge);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PostWallServlet",
        data: { message : mge  }
      }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      });
}
        </script>
      <form name="form1" method="GET" action="PostWallServlet" id="form1"></form>

      <table border="0" width="100%">  
            <tr>  
                <td colspan="3">  ${message}</td>  
            </tr>  


            <tr>  
                <td>Sender</td>  
                <td>:</td>  
                <td><input type="text" name="sender" value="" size=20/></td>  
            </tr> 
            <tr>  
                <td>Post</td>  
                <td>:</td>  
                <td><input type="text" name="post" value="" size=500 id="newText"/ ></td>  
            </tr>  



            <tr>  
                <td></td>  
                <td></td>  
                <td><input type="submit" value="Add" name="Add" /></td>  
            </tr>  
        </table>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Put your ending tag for form AFTER all your inputs:

```
<form name="form1" method="GET" action="PostWallServlet" id="form1">
...
<td><input type="text" name="sender" value="" size=20 /></td>
...    
<td><input type="text" name="post" value="" size=500 id="newText" /></td>  
...
<td><input type="submit" value="Add" name="Add" /></td>  
...
</form>
```

Your inputs must be INSIDE the form, not after the form.

Also make sure to end your input tags with /> not / >.  You have a space between / and > on one of them.

For the Ajax part you need to give your inputs ids as well as names:

```
<td><input type="text" name="sender" id="sender" value="" size=20 /></td>
```

And then in your Ajax function for data:

```
 data: { sender: $('#sender').val(), post:  $('#post').val() }
```

Comment: got that...but you don't know how to solve the problem?

Comment: What problem does it not solve? To use the same servlet for get and post?  Just make a doGet method that does a call to `doPost(request, response);`

Comment: i just want post within ajax...and sender should be picked up from within the servlet..thats my problem

Comment: Hence why you need to change `data: { message : mge  }` to `data: { sender: $('#sender').val(), post:  $('#post').val() }` You're sending a parameter named message, so obviously when you try to read a parameter named sender it isn't going to be there.